# How to disable TypeScript code validation in VSCode for specific unit tests folder?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, typescript-eslint

How can I disable the VSCode code validation of TypeScript in my unit test files (Jest unit tests), the 2 issues that comes up most often are `'undefined' is not assignable to x` and `object is possibly undefined` but I don't care in unit tests that is just normal in such files.

When I first wrote the question I thought it was ESLint, but ended up finding that it's actually VSCode code validation and I wish that I could disable just these 2 errors/rules

- `'undefined' is not assignable to x`
- `object is possibly undefined`

To give a bit more of a background, my library is a wrapper on top of a JavaScript library and even though it's written in TypeScript it can also be used in ES6 syntax, so in certain occasion I need to make sure assigning undefined/null values are throwing defined errors as expected (even if it's not technically possible TypeScript), so I want to disable those 2 rules for unit testing only.

For example this error shown below, I know my object is filled and is not undefined because of how I wrote the unit test but still TypeScript complains that it might be undefined. I could add casting to make sure TypeScript knows it's filled but I seriously just wish to disable the rule for unit test files. I just don't want to have to cast everything to tell TypeScript that it's not undefined.

[image]

I could be specific and tell TypeScript that it's not undefined (as shown below with `!.`), but again I wish I could just skip that rule and not have to revisit all my test files. I find this counter-productive, my unit test is for testing that the method is really being called, I know the object is filled, I don't want TS to complain that it might be undefined on those lines.

[image]

I know I could add a bunch of `// @ts-ignore` but I really wish to bypass these rules in unit test. Are there any VSCode setting that I could use for that?

EDIT

I basically have the same problem as this VSCode [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66017) and adding `// @ts-nocheck` on top of the file does work but I would have to add this to hundred of files, I wish there would be an easier way to fix this problem. I want to exclude unit test folder, that should be simple

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the error code on the error. In this instance it's `ts(2322)`. As the code suggests - it's a *typescript* error.
This has nothing to do with ESLint. ESLint reports are clearly coded as `eslint(...)`.

---

TypeScript is validating your code, as it does for all `.ts` and `.tsx` files.

There are two recommended ways to escape from the type system:

- use a `@ts-ignore` or `@ts-expect-error` comment to explicitly suppress the typecheck error on the next line.
- use an assertion to any (`foo as any`) to explicitly widen the type unsafely.

These are the intended workarounds for "I'm doing something that is not valid according to the types".

Why do you want to write so much type-invalid code?

You shouldn't be escaping more than a handful of times in an entire project.
Even for a test file where things can get spooky, the vast, vast, vast majority of your code should be written in a typesafe manner.

Otherwise you could very easily introduce accidental regressions and the like during refactors that wouldn't otherwise be caught.

For example - in your screenshot you have `gridStub.getColumns = undefined`

Now imagine that you refactor `SlickGrid.getColumns` to instead be named `SlickGrid.getColumnsFoo`. Now your test is executing invalid code.

If you instead use an `any` to escape the type assignment error: `gridStub.getColumns = (undefined as any)`, then TS will ignore the fact that the assignment is invalid, but will still error if you rename the property.

If you really want to stop your test files from being checked, then stop using TS entirely - rename them to `.js`/`.jsx`. But this is seriously not recommended.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough but I do care a lot about being Type safe in all my files EXCEPT the unit test files, I most often test by assigning undefined/null to test some possible error thrown. My library is a wrapper of JavaScript library, everything is possible and I need to test everything even when it's not technically possible in TypeScript as it might still happen, my lib is also used in ES6 syntax so again I must make sure that I test error thrown with undefined/null values... both recommendations are already mentioned in my question, and your downvote & answer aren't helping

Comment: But like. You're typing `null`. With 9 extra characters you could make it an any and thus make TS ignore it. The last part of my answer is what you want. If you want to disable all TS checks for a file, then rename the test files to `.js` to disable ts from running on those files and showing errors in vscode.